# Sequence in vector space $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

Are set of sequences satisfying the conditions (a) or (b) vector subspaces of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$?

Sequence $(a_n)_n\in\mathbb N$ for $\forall n \in \mathbb N$

$$(a)\, a_{n+2} = 4a_{n+1} − a_n$$
$$(b)\, a_{n+1} = 4a_n − 2.$$

In my mind I have to calculate it and get $(a_n)$. But I dont understand how to do it for this...

Comment: What is exactly the question?

Comment: Are you sure you have copied this problem correctly?  $R^n$ a set of finite sequences (each with n numbers) while your "subspace" consists of infinite sequences.

Comment: I need to know if this sequences (a,b) are subspace for R^n and fulfill with conditions. Maybe I used bad terms... but dont know how to translate to english correctly.

Comment: The sequences $(a_n)$ are not elements of $\mathbb{R}^d$ for any finite $d$.  They are elements of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, if we define that to be the set of all sequences of real numbers.  Perhaps you are asking if the set of sequences satisfying the conditions (a) or (b) are vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: You are right, I changed the question. Thank you!

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Do you know the definition of a "subspace"?  Have you tried applying it in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (a) we have the characteristic polynomial $r^2 - 4r +1=$ which has roots $r=2\pm\sqrt 3$. So $$a_n = c_1(2+\sqrt 3)^n + c_2(2-\sqrt 3)^n.$$ The set of such sequences $a_n$, denote it by $A$, is a subspace of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ since $0\in A$ and if $x=c_1(2+\sqrt 3)^n + c_2(2-\sqrt 3)^n, y = d_1(2+\sqrt 3)^n + d_2(2-\sqrt 3)^n\in A$ then for $c\in\mathbb R$
\begin{align} cx &= c(c_1(2+\sqrt 3)^n + c_2(2-\sqrt 3)^n)\\
&= cc_1(2+\sqrt 3)^n + cc_2(2-\sqrt3)^n\\
&=  c_1'(2+\sqrt 3)^n + c_2'(2-\sqrt 3)^n\in A
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
x+y &= c_1(2+\sqrt 3)^n + c_2(2-\sqrt 3)^n + d_1(2+\sqrt 3)^n + d_2(2-\sqrt 3)^n\\
&= (c_1 + d_1)(2+\sqrt 3)^n + (c_2+d_2)(2-\sqrt 3)^n\\
&= c_1'(2+\sqrt 3)^n + c_2'(2-\sqrt 3)^n\in A.
\end{align}

For (b) we have a nonhomogeneous recurrence relation (due to the $-2$ term), so the solution is of the form
$$
a_n = a_n^h + a_n^p
$$
where $a_n^h$ is a solution to the corresponding homogeneous recurrence relation and $a_n^p$ is a particular solution to the nonhomogeneous recurrence relation. We can see immediately from $a_{n+1} = 4a_n$ that $a_n^h = c_14^{n-1}$, and the particular solution is of the form $p$ for some constant $p$. Substituting, we have
$$
p = 4p - 2\implies p=\frac23.
$$
So the general solution to the recurrence relation is $a_n=c_14^{n-1}+\frac23$. But clearly for $c\in\mathbb R\setminus 0$ we have
$$
c\left(c_14^{n-1}+\frac23\right) = c_1' 4^{n-1} + \frac23 c,
$$
which is not a sequence of the same form. So the set of sequences satisfying the recurrence relation in (b) is *not* a vector space.